# play + sorm. Can't find symbol sorm._

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sorm

I know that there are a lot of same issues. But I've seen many topics and I have another problem.

Simple situation - I download new play activator, create simple play-scala example, watch tutorial video on main page. try to reproduce and ...

When I add dependency of sorm - all is ok. Ide show me that sorm library is downloaded and assist me some methods from sorm.Instance. But during compilation I receive error "cannot resolve symbol sorm._"

I've read few topics to understand problems with compability of play and sorm. But [one](https://devhacksandgoodies.wordpress.com/2014/12/07/how-to-include-sorm-0-4-1-to-your-play-application/) tell me that there is new vesion and it must works. - sorry, I have same problem.

Does anyone know where problem is?